# Airline rebooked flight to one that is cheaper for them - can I insist on the shortest alternative?

Tags: air-travel, passenger-rights, ec261, flight-changes

I booked a return ticket Stockholm (ARN) - Amman (AMM) - Aquaba (AQJ) and AQJ-AMM-ARN with Royal Jordanian Airlines. They  emailed me that the first leg, ARN-AMM, has been cancelled.

EC261 rules clearly apply here, as the flight departs from the EU. As I understand, I am [entitled to reimbursement or "re-routing, under comparable transport conditions, to their final destination at the earliest opportunity"](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#reimbursement-cancellation-1). (No compensation as they notified me more than 14 days in advance.)

I asked to be rebooked with Turkish Airlines via Istanbul (ARN-IST-AQJ) departing the same day as originally booked. They don't want to do that, because that flight is expensive (only a few semi-flexible fares are left), and are instead trying to rebook me on BA via London (ARN-LHR-AMM-AQJ). That's much cheaper for them as only the ARN-LHR leg is on BA and the rest on RJ.

Their routing *does* get me to my destination (AQJ) at the originally scheduled time, but:

- involves more flying - I have to depart earlier, and spend an extra 70 minutes on a plane compared to the TK option
- involves an extra stop
- gets me to Amman at 00:05 instead of 22:00 in the original booking, so even that layover, although originally planned, becomes more inconvenient

Do I have any right to insist on the shorter, more convenient, more expensive TK itinerary or can they rebook me on whatever is cheapest for them?

I'm aware that I can book flights myself and claim reimbursement for them later, but that seems *very* risky, as Royal Jordanian is obviously not headquartered in the EU. Even if I go to a
court in Sweden, can it even force the airline to pay?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer nor a flight rights expert, but 70 minutes more on a plane compared to an overall travel time of 7-10 hours is something I would still consider "comparable transport conditions".

Comment: I agree completely with Sabine and what Jordanian is doing here is common practice. *All* airlines will first try to re-route you on their own flights or flights operated by affiliated airlines before they buy you a ticket from a competitor.

Comment: Some interesting reading: https://www.caa.co.uk/publication/download/18744 see chapter 4. Also footnote 14 and all the references in chapter 2. You'll see that their approach is quite balanced, so it seems unlikely that if they were the regulator involved here they would side with you. While YMMV you would indeed be taking quite a risk.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for that CAA link @jcaron. That footnote 14 you mention refers to [EC Interpretative Guidelines](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A52016XC0615%2801%29) which also say (section 4.2): "the following good practices are recommended: ...  reasonable efforts are to be made to avoid additional connections" - so that point seems to be in my favour.

Comment: @EM0 that’s probably not what I would take “reasonable efforts” to mean.

Comment: While I don't have enough information to actually answer, IMO, adding a country (or even a different state in the US) to your route which is not of your choosing could be catastrophic for some individuals, even without considering citizenship and potential visa issues. As such, I think it would be reasonable to argue that the route they proposed is not "under comparable transport conditions", due to forcing the transit of a different country which isn't of your choosing.

Comment: Just FYI, if you do end up on BA LHR to AMM, bring your own food. I took that flight in the opposite direction, and there was no food or drink on offer at all on board, even for purchase. Which was weird, because my flight LHR to TLV on BA a week earlier had had full meal service for a shorter flight.

Comment: @Makyen I don't think that's a reasonable argumentation, unless a traveller can present a reason why a specific country is out of bounds for them. But claiming that a different transit airport makes flights not comparable for anyone, just because it could cause problems for a few individuals, seems excessive.

Comment: @A.R. This is all thanks to the previous CEO of BA, Alex Cruz, deciding to halve the size of its galleys on its short-haul fleet to add additional seating. Because of the now-tiny galley sizes, the only thing they can do is offer meals to purchase in advance of the flight. It appears they're now renovating their short-haul cabins - hopefully they make the galleys bigger again.

Comment: @gparyani It's nearly a six-hour flight; not really what I'd call "short-haul." And like I said, on LHR-TLV, which is only a five-hour flight, they served hot breakfast.

Comment: Bear in mind, that you might need a transit visa for the UK, which could be a reason for you to demand the route outside of the UK if you need the visa https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa

Answer (score 24):

Royal Jordanian is in the Oneworld alliance, while Turkish is in the competing Star Alliance, so it will be quite difficult to convince RJ to endorse (pay for your ticket) on Turkish.  This also explains why they want to send you via London on British Airways, because BA is a fellow Oneworld member.

More generally, if an airline changes your flights unilaterally, your choices are to accept the alternative or get a full refund and book somewhere else.  You can always try to negotiate, but without frequent flyer status or an expensive business class ticket that gets you access to priority hotlines, you're unlikely to get very far.

Comment: would seem to be the whole story - take the refund